# How does Meat Grinder mode affect death saving throw probabilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, statistics, tomb-of-annihilation

The module *Tomb of Annihilation* features an optional 'Meat Grinder' mode. By using this optional rule, the difficulty of death saving throws is increased from 10 to 15.

The probabilities of living or dying based solely on death save successes and failures are discussed [in this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76958/what-is-the-probability-of-surviving-my-death-saves). How does the 'Meat Grinder' rule affect these probabilities?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modified the [spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqtWvvJ4b57jjnqyuuO308CDv9tK).

If left unattended the outcomes are:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{Outcome} & \text{Normal} & \text{Meat Grinder}\\
\hline
\text{1hp} & 0.181 & 0.170\\
\text{Stable} & 0.414 & 0.088\\
\text{Dead} & 0.405 & 0.742\\
\end{array}
$$

So, your chance of surviving drops from just under 60% to just over 25%.